# How to Place XML Node Value as Label Component's Text Value (in Flash/AS3)?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm querying an XML web service and am parsing 3 nodes per the code below.  I want to send the resulting value to a label component.  When I place the Label component on stage, and name it lowtemp_label, remove the default text value of Label and play the SWF, nothing shows up.  How do I ensure that the lowtemp_label gets the returned low temp value?

```
private function onXmlLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
        var resultXML:XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
        trace(resultXML.cc.tmp);
        trace(resultXML.cc.flik);
        trace(resultXML.cc.icon);

        var lowtemp_label :TextField = new TextField();
        addChild(lowtemp_label)
        var hitemp_label :TextField=new TextField();
        addChild(hitemp_label)
        var condicon_label :TextField=new TextField();
        addChild(condicon_label)

        lowtemp_label.text=resultXML.cc.tmp;
        hitemp_label.text=resultXML.cc.flik;
        condicon_label.text=resultXML.cc.icon;
        }
```

Thanks much:)

Comment: Are the traces returning the correct values? Are you using the label component or are you creating a new TextField? In the provided code, it looks like you're just creating a new TextField called "lowtemp_label".

Comment: Yes, the traces are grabbing the correct values.  Should I sub out LabelField for TextField in my code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your Document class (using the Flash IDE) and you have a label component on the stage, just remove the chunk of code where you're creating a new TextField.

```
var lowtemp_label :TextField = new TextField();
addChild(lowtemp_label)
```

In your code, "lowtemp_label" is a TextField instance in the scope of the function...you probably want to reference the label component that is on the stage and outside of the function scope.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying to change my vat statement to Var lowtemp_label : LabelField = lowtemp_label(); ?

Comment: Does it matter if the script I've written is placed in a separate .as file?  Or should it go in the Actions window on the timeline?  Thanks:)

Comment: I'm suggesting you remove it completely. If this code is within your Document class (like "Main.as") and the label component is on frame 1 of your root timeline, you can reference the label by it's instance name...in this case "lowtemp_label". Otherwise, if you need to create it and add it to the stage, then you would need to first create the object like "var lowtemp_label:Label = new Label();"

Comment: I've removed the var and AddChild statements.  When I try lowtemp_label.text = trace(resultXML.cc.tmp);, I receive Error 1067 Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type String.  Do I change my function to onXmlLoaded(Event:event):string ?

Comment: Your code would actually be lowtemp_label.text = String(resultXML.cc.tmp);